# CI for monthly production based on daily production data

Tags: confidence-interval

Say I have 16 work days in a month, and I have 16 days of production data so that I have a mean and variance for this daily data (e.g. mean is 3750 and variance is 500).

I can construct a confidence interval for the daily data, but how do I inflate the interval width to construct a confidence interval of the same level of confidence for the mean monthly production? That is, if I make a 95% confidence interval for the daily mean I also want a 95% confidence interval for the monthly mean.

[You could created a very large CI around the one monthly production datum, but that is not what I am interested in.]

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you'd want some kind of model for the daily data (are Mondays different from Thursdays? Are weekdays different from Sundays? Is there dependence across days? Are there available, useful predictors?), and then apply that model for the rest of the month, aggregated.

Comment: I should have said in the question that data are i.i.d, but if there are daily predictors that isn't important (for me). I just don't know how to adjust the variance based on daily data to make a confidence interval for the aggregated monthly mean (which doesn't really exist yet because there is only one month of data).

Comment: the main thing to do is how to correctly calculate your $s^2$ estimate for the aggregation of months. to do this you need to describe a model. for example, is the variance constant around the monthly means?

Comment: Hmmm, it sounds to me like there is no randomness here.  It sounds to me like you have collected all the data for every possible workday in a month (i.e. there was/is no sampling).  In this case, there are no confidence intervals. You already know the exact total produced (and hence the average although $n=1$ month).  Now, if there was some sampling done or you wanted to make inferences to a larger population (perhaps you only collected data for one month, but want to obtain CIs for the past two years), then you need to specify in your question what your population of interest is.

Answer (score 0):

The mean monthly production $\bar{x}$ (=3750) is calculated from a sample size of 16, the 16 days in the month. If you wanted a confidence interval for the mean for a specific day, then you would only have one sample (the value for that day) and a very large confidence interval. However, over the whole month, you are using 16 samples, the data for each of the 16 days.

I will assume that the variance has been estimated from the data and is not known and I will denote it as $s^2$. The confidence interval is then, generally (assuming independent and identically distributed samples from a normal population), for a (1-$\alpha$)% confidence interval:

\begin{equation}
\bar{x}\pm t_{n-1,\alpha/2}\times\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{n}}.
\end{equation}

For your example, a 95% confidence interval is

\begin{equation}
3750\pm 2.131\times\dfrac{\sqrt{500}}{4}=(3738.087,3761.913).
\end{equation}

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The mean daily production is 3750, and I know how to calculate a confidence interval around that mean. What I don't know how to do is to adapt that confidence interval to an aggregate monthly production of 60000.

Comment: Okay, I understand your question better now, thanks for the clarification. If you strongly believe there is no difference between the production for each day, then you can simply adapt the confidence interval provided in my example. Say you have 50 samples a day over the 16 days, then you have n=800 samples over the 16 days. You would calculate the mean and sample standard deviation over all 800 samples and, thus, have the smaller confidence interval because you have a larger number of samples.